# Express renders index.html but no other page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an express app to just serve static html files.

```
let express = require('express');
let path = require('path');
let cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
let logger = require('morgan');

let indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
let usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
let appRouter = require('./routes/app');

let app = express();

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/app', appRouter);

module.exports = app;
```

In `/public` I have `index.html` and `app.html`

In `/routes/` I have `index.js` and `app.js`

Both of them are basically identical

**index.js**

```
let express = require('express');
let router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('index');
});

module.exports = router;
```

**app.js**

```
let express = require('express');
let router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('app');
});

module.exports = router;
```

When I access `localhost:3000` the `index.html` file is displayed perfectly.

When I access `localhost:3000/app` I get the error

> Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.
>       at new View (C:\a\Web\todo\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:61:11)
>       at Function.render (C:\a\Web\todo\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:570:12)
>       at ServerResponse.render (C:\a\Web\todo\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1008:7)
>       at C:\Voliware\Web\todo\routes\app.js:5:9
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\a\Web\todo\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (C:\a\Web\todo\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (C:\a\Web\todo\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\a\Web\todo\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at C:\a\Web\todo\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
>       at Function.process_params (C:\a\Web\todo\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)

Answer (score 1):

You said 'just serve static html files.'. then mark the following 3 lines.

`// app.use('/', indexRouter);
// app.use('/users', usersRouter);
// app.use('/app', appRouter);`

and access `access localhost:3000/app.html` not `access localhost:3000/app`. because you don't have a static file named 'app'.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your middle ware stack

`app.set('view engine', 'html');`

Comment: Error: Cannot find module 'html'